# How to distinct data object and Sum the value that are d same

Tags: javascript, object

How can i distinct my object value and add the value that is the same in Zone.

Given the data below i want to get the Distinct Zone and Sum up all totalItemQuantity that are the same with Zone number. using javascript, this is pretty much easy in LINQ however im using reactjs and linq seems not working with react.

```
{
    "Zone": "4",
    "totalItemQuantity": 54
},
{
    "Zone": "4",
    "totalItemQuantity": 33
},
{
    "Zone": "6",
    "totalItemQuantity": 209
},
{
    "Zone": "6",
    "totalItemQuantity": 182
},
{
    "Zone": "8",
    "totalItemQuantity": 13
}
```

and the result should be like this

```
data = [
    {
    "Zone": "4",
    "totalItemQuantity": 87
    },
    {
    "Zone": "6",
    "totalItemQuantity": 391
    },
    {
    "Zone": "8",
    "totalItemQuantity": 13
    },
]
```

Heres my attemp. note: props.warehousedetails is my array data. im using reactjs

```
var test = [...new Set(props.warehousedetails.map((data) => data.Zone))].sort().map(x => ({
    zone: x, data: props.warehousedetails.filter(data => {
        let assignmentObj = null;
        if(data.Zone === x ){
            assignmentObj = Object.entries(data).map(data=>{
                return data.totalItemQuantity;
            })
        }
        return assignmentObj;
    })
}));
```

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce` and group your object based on `Zone` and add the `totalItemQuantity` in an object and then take out all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [{ "Zone": "4", "totalItemQuantity": 54 }, { "Zone": "4", "totalItemQuantity": 33 }, { "Zone": "6", "totalItemQuantity": 209 }, { "Zone": "6", "totalItemQuantity": 182 }, { "Zone": "8", "totalItemQuantity": 13 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.Zone] = r[o.Zone] || {Zone: o.Zone, totalItemQuantity: 0};
      r[o.Zone].totalItemQuantity += o.totalItemQuantity;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```